# pycharm pandas not module http client error in only some files, runs in console

Tags: python, pandas, http, pycharm

Pycharm is giving me a

```
AttributeError: module 'http' has no attribute 'client'
```

when trying to load in pandas for a specific file. Strangely I only get this error if I also have the following import:

```
from sklearn import svm
```

pandas is with the Anaconda package suite, and runs/loads without the sklearn module, and in the console.

Python 3.7, Github extension, anaconda suite. I have tried reinstall pandas and sklearn to no avail. I have tried reordering my file structure to avoid python path issues.

```
python
import pandas
from sklearn import svm
```

I expect the code to compile as there are no noticeable syntax errors and even with the rest of the code commented out this still happens.

edit: it compiles when run in the console, so there appears to be an issue with the python path. Is there a way to investigate this more closely or directly control the python path? Also it compiles when I run with

```
import sklearn
```

but does not with

```
from sklearn import svm
```

if that helps narrow down the issue at all...

Comment: I would start by looking at your version of PyCharm.  There were path issues in some of the 2018 versions.  I'm currently running v2019.2.1 Pro and these imports are not an issue.

Comment: [PyCharm Won't Import Module (Numpy) Even Though It Shows It's Installed](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360001029680-PyCharm-Won-t-Import-Module-Numpy-Even-Though-It-Shows-It-s-Installed) this I think is the same issue...It occurs with more than numpy

Comment: The weird thing is that this is a new problem for me and may have to do with the fact I save my python files in dropbox (between laptop and desktop). But normally it was working fine and in other files it also works just fine. Ill check my pycharm version, though.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be that my file is named ssl.py I don't know if there's another file called that which was cauing path issues but it seems to be fixed now...